# Why is there a difference in CSV Export Results of Oracle SQL Developer and SQL Plus Spool

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle-sql-developer, csv

When I export data from SQL Developer GUI, setting `format: csv`, `left enclosure: "`, `right enclosure: "`, and `Encoding: UTF8`, I get data exactly the way that I need it for processing in Python.

However, when I attempt to do the same thing from SQL Plus, I get very different results. Here are my settings (file.sql is simply a select statement):

```
export ORACLE_SID=MYSID
sqlplus / as sysdba <<EOF
conn myUser/myPass 
set heading off
set termout off 
set trimout off
set newpage none
set pages 0
set feedback off
set echo off
set verify off
set trimspool on
set sqlprompt "" 
set colsep ","
set linesize 32767      
@/home/username/file.sql
exit
EOF
```

How can I export the data from SQL Plus so that it is exactly like that from SQL Developer? As an FYI, when I run `file -i myfile.csv` I get "application/octet-stream; charset=binary", while from SQL Plus the file is some form of "ASCII" (and for some tables "ISO").

Comment: Because they are different commands? You can spool from SQL Developer, which would be much more similar. What exactly is different between the outputs? Just saying it is very different isn't very helpful. You haven't shown the query you're running, either, which might be relevant.

Comment: What Alex said. HOW is it different? Also, why would you expect them to be the same, formatting-wise? Also, for what it's worth, our new SQLcl command line tool supports CSV formatting, just run your query with select /*csv*/ from ... and you're done.